# Help with install of cuDNN

Tags: nvidia, cuda

I am trying to install both cuda and cudnn. I have GTX 780M, CUDA 7.5 and compute capability 3.0. I have the following below

```
haziq@haziq-P15SM:~/Downloads$ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2015 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_Aug_11_14:27:32_CDT_2015
Cuda compilation tools, release 7.5, V7.5.17
```

Does this mean that CUDA is already installed ? And that I can already begin installing CUDnn ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it has already installed. you can install cuDNN. Just follow the official guide [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/cudnn-install/index.html#installlinux) It is pretty easy. Because it is not actually installing but copying the files into the right directory.